# tryCatch suppress error message

Tags: r, exception

I am using `tryCatch` to catch any errors that occur. However, even though I catch them and return the appropriate error value, it looks like the error is still reported in the logs of my batch system. Is there a way to completely suppress the error and simply proceed with the error handling I provide?

Comment: what does 'return the appropriate error value' mean here? if you're returning an error from an error handler then it makes sense they show up. you could return nothing `tryCatch(expr, function(e) {})` (possibly first checking if `e` meets some conditions

Comment: let me clarify: I'm currently not returning an error explicitly from my error handler function. However, I do print the message via `message(cond)` where `cond` is the error condition. Is this the reason it's showing up? ie message is actually sending things to stderr instead of stdout? if so i missed that in the help file

Comment: in other words: if i don't `message(cond)` then no error should be visible correct?

Comment: yes, see the first paragraph of Details in `?message`; and yes, if you don't `message(cond)` then you shouldn't see anything.

Comment: I'm honestly surprised too that `message` 1) defaults to stderr, 2) provides no (obvious) way to send to stdout instead. :shug:

Comment: that solves it then. if you want to put in an answer to close the question, i'll accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you're neither (1) returning an error, nor (2) printing to `stderr` in your error handling code. Note one gotcha here is `message` sends its output to `stderr`.

A minimal way to fulfills both conditions is `tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {})`