# Error Handling with do.call

Tags: r, loops, time-series, vectorization, do.call

I have the code below which creates a matrix with every possible combination of 3 parameters, and then creates an arima model for each set of parameters.  Sometimes the fitter step where it trains the models will throw an error and quit.  I would like to modify the code so that if fitter throws an error instead of quitting it just skips that combination of parameters and goes on to the next row in the matrix.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
library("fpp")

dataTrain <- window(hsales,end=1989.99)

p1<-1:10
d1<-1:2
q1<-1:7

paramtrix<-expand.grid(p1,d1,q1)

modbuilder <- function(a,b,c) {Arima(dataTrain, order=c(a,b,c))}
fitter <- do.call(Vectorize(modbuilder, SIMPLIFY=FALSE), unname(paramtrix))
```

Update:

```
## Forecasting/Accuracy of models
funcCast<-function(x){forecast(x,h=20)$mean}
ModCast<-lapply(fitter,funcCast)

ModAcc<-function(x){accuracy(x,tsTest)[1,5]}
TestAcc<-lapply(ModCast,ModAcc)

##Find Model that minimizes mape

Acc_res<-do.call(rbind,TestAcc)
res_num <- which(Acc_res==min(Acc_res))  
res_model<-fitter[[res_num]] ## Error being introduced by NAN
```

Comment: wrapping the `Arima` in a `tryCatch` may work. try the code here (but replace `expr` with your `Arima(dataTrain, order=c(a,b,c))` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683031/trycatch-suppress-error-message/36683369#36683369

Comment: @jaimedash Thank you!  tryCatch did the trick.

Comment: cool. I posted that as an answer but if it didnt' work as written, feel free to edit that answer or post your own. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
Arima(dataTrain, order=c(a,b,c))
```

with

```
tryCatch(Arima(dataTrain, order=c(a,b,c)), error = function(e) {})
```

Comment: Hey if you'd like to go for bonus points I've added the next few steps in my code, where I forecast the models, and then pick out the model that minimizes the mape.  I'm getting an error now in the final step because I think NAN are getting introduced by the tryCatch.  I would like to just skip the NAN and return the model that minimizes the mape.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hey, sorry I'm not sure. I did just start to run your code but it was taking too long before I had to leave. you should 1) cut your example down in size to just include a fit that gives `NaN` and 2) (if you want to get anyone else to try to answer it) write a new question. (You could link back to this one from it, but try to make it self contained)

Comment: oops maybe don't need to run your code. try `Acc_res = Acc_res[!is.nan(Acc_res)]` before your final step