# using `tryCatch` and printing error message when expression fails

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I am attempting to write a custom function which carries out the goodness of fit test using `chisq.test` (below is a toy version of it). I want the function to be robust so I am using `tryCatch` to make sure that if invalid probability vectors are specified, the function returns a dataframe with `NaN`s.

Here is the function-

```r
set.seed(123)

# custom function
custom_prop <- function(var, ratio) {
  tryCatch(
    expr = broom::tidy(stats::chisq.test(
      x = table(var),
      p = ratio
    )),
    error = function(x) {
      tibble::tribble(
        ~statistic, ~p.value, ~parameter,
        NaN, NaN, NaN
      )
    }
  )
}
```

**trying out valid ratios** (vector sums to 1; works as expected)

```r
custom_prop(mtcars$am, c(0.6, 0.4))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   statistic p.value parameter method                                  
#>       <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                                   
#> 1   0.00521   0.942         1 Chi-squared test for given probabilities

custom_prop(mtcars$am, c(0.7, 0.3))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   statistic p.value parameter method                                  
#>       <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                                   
#> 1      1.72   0.190         1 Chi-squared test for given probabilities
```

**trying out invalid ratios** (vector doesn't sum to 1; works as expected)

```r
custom_prop(mtcars$am, c(0.6, 0.6))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   statistic p.value parameter
#>       <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1       NaN     NaN       NaN

custom_prop(mtcars$am, c(0.7, 0.5))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   statistic p.value parameter
#>       <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1       NaN     NaN       NaN
```

But the problem with this approach is that the user has no clue why the function didn't return results. If I were to not use `tryCatch`, they will see why-

```r
broom::tidy(stats::chisq.test(
  x = table(mtcars$am),
  p = c(0.7,0.5)
))
#> Error in stats::chisq.test(x = table(mtcars$am), p = c(0.7, 0.5)): probabilities must sum to 1.
```

I also tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683031/trycatch-suppress-error-message), but this just returns a NULL without printing an error message-

```r
# custom function
custom_prop2 <- function(var, ratio) {
  tryCatch(
    expr = broom::tidy(stats::chisq.test(
      x = table(var),
      p = ratio
    )),
    error = function(e) {}
  )
}

# trying out invalid ratios
custom_prop2(mtcars$am, c(0.6, 0.6))
#> NULL
```

So, **my question is**-
Is there any way to use `tryCatch` and **also** print the error message when the expression fails to work?

Comment: You have to print the `x` (or whatever variable you pass into anonymous function) in error block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the error message to build and throw a `warning` instead:

```
custom_prop <- function(var, ratio) {
  tryCatch(
    expr = broom::tidy(stats::chisq.test(
      x = table(var),
      p = ratio
    )),
    error = function(x) {
      warning(x)   # just add this line
      tibble::tribble(
        ~statistic, ~p.value, ~parameter,
        NaN, NaN, NaN
      )
    }
  )
}

custom_prop(mtcars$am, c(0.6, 0.6))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  statistic p.value parameter
#      <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#1       NaN     NaN       NaN
#Warning message:
#In stats::chisq.test(x = table(var), p = ratio) :
#  probabilities must sum to 1.
```